# E_INVALIDARG while IMFTransform::ProcessOutput

Tags: visual-c++, sdk, signal-processing, video-processing, ms-media-foundation

I am struggling to make cartoon shader in Media Foundation, and to do so I need to convert NV12 provided by my camera natively to RGB24. By far my tries with IMFTransform looks like this:
Setup:

```
inputVideoTypes = new MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO;
inputVideoTypes->guidMajorType = MFMediaType_Video;
inputVideoTypes->guidSubtype = MFVideoFormat_NV12;
outputVideoTypes = new MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO;
outputVideoTypes->guidMajorType = MFMediaType_Video;
outputVideoTypes->guidSubtype = MFVideoFormat_RGB24;
IMFActivate **transformActivateArray = NULL;
UINT32 MFTcount;
hr = MFTEnumEx(MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_PROCESSOR, MFT_ENUM_FLAG_ALL, inputVideoTypes, outputVideoTypes, &transformActivateArray, &MFTcount);
hr = VP->GetAttributes(&VPAttributes);
hr = VPAttributes->SetUINT32(MF_TOPOLOGY_ENABLE_XVP_FOR_PLAYBACK, TRUE);
hr = VP->SetInputType(0, streamType2, 0);
MediaFoundationSamples::LogMediaType(streamType2);
DWORD dwIndex = 4;
hr = VP->GetOutputAvailableType(0, dwIndex, &streamType3);
hr = MFSetAttributeSize(streamType3, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 1280, 720);
hr = streamType3->SetUINT32(MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES, 1);
hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(streamType3, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 30, 1);
hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(streamType3, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
streamType3->SetUINT32(MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, 1);
streamType3->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, 2);
MediaFoundationSamples::LogMediaType(streamType3);
hr = VP->SetOutputType(0, streamType3, 0);
hr = VP->GetInputStreamInfo(0, &InputInfo);
hr = VP->GetOutputStreamInfo(0, &OutputInfo);
```

InOnReadSample:

```
hr = VP->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_BEGIN_STREAMING, NULL);
hr = VP->ProcessInput(0, sample, 0);
DWORD statusFlags;
hr = VP->GetOutputStatus(&statusFlags);
while (statusFlags == 0)
{
    hr = VP->ProcessInput(0, sample, 0);
    hr = VP->GetOutputStatus(&statusFlags);
}
DWORD outputStatus = 0;
IMFSample* outputSample;
MFCreateSample(&outputSample);
MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER outputBuffer = {};
outputBuffer.pSample = outputSample;
hr = VP->ProcessOutput(0, 1, &outputBuffer, &outputStatus);
```

But the problem is that ProcessOutput returns hr = E_INVALIDARG and I have no idea why. Weird things are OutputInfo and InputInfo. both dwFlags are 0, but their cbSize seems normal.

Logs of MediaTypes:

input (streamType2):

```
MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE    1280 x 720
MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX    2
MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE    MFMediaType_Video
MF_MT_VIDEO_LIGHTING    3
MF_MT_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITING   1
MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE    {F72A76A0-EB0A-11D0-ACE4-0000C0CC16BA}
MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES    1
MF_MT_VIDEO_NOMINAL_RANGE   1
MF_MT_FRAME_RATE    30 x 1
MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO    1 x 1
MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT   1
MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN  128849018881
MF_MT_VIDEO_PRIMARIES   2
MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE    2
MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX  128849018881
{EA031A62-8BBB-43C5-B5C4-572D2D231C18}  1
MF_MT_SUBTYPE   MFVideoFormat_NV12
```

output (streamType3):

```
MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE    1280 x 720
MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE    MFMediaType_Video
MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES    1
MF_MT_FRAME_RATE    30 x 1
MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO    1 x 1
MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT   1
MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE    2
MF_MT_SUBTYPE   MFVideoFormat_RGB24
```

Is anyone able to tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried letting the Video Processor transform allocate the output sample? I.e. comment out the following line: outputBuffer.pSample = outputSample;

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but it's no use.

Comment: If you are certain that VP is the Video Processor MFT then maybe it requires a 3D manager and directx surface samples on its output

Comment: And what exactly will I need to do toprovide 3D Manager and those surface samples? I am doing according to https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/desktop/medfound/basic-mft-processing-model#basic-processing-model, and there is no mention of anything like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to convert buffers without setting up Direct3D awareness. This is fine for memory buffers and in this mode you are typically supposed to provide both input and output buffers yourselves. Zero `OutputInfo.dwFlags` suggests exactly this.

So you are on the right track there with your `MFT_OUTPUT_DATA_BUFFER::pSample` initialization but what kind of sample you are submitting for output? It is a sample with no buffer attached. Hence, invalid argument.

Use [`MFCreateMemoryBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfapi/nf-mfapi-mfcreatememorybuffer) to allocate memory for your output RGB24 sample and then use it in `ProcessOutput` call.

Comment: The way you ask across questions is overly expensive to respond. You should consider making a small test project with a problem you are trying to solve, then put it on GitHub, reference in your new StackOverflow question and then it will be easy to handle to those to help you.